# Acessando outro APP dentro do meu com OAuth 2.0

Tags: java, android, ios, swift

Como usar OAuth 2.0  para alterar de Apps. Tenho alguns Apps e quero que dentro dele conseguimos acessar outros Apps(do mesmo fornecedor), sem precisar realizar o login novamente.

Answer (score 0):

O android oferece um mini tutorial de como voce pode conseguir realizar isso na [pagina de desenvolvimento](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/sending.html) deles

> Embora a plataforma do Android garanta que determinados intents sejam
>   resolvidos com um dos aplicativos embutidos (como aplicativo de
>   Telefone, E-mail ou Agenda), sempre inclua uma etapa de confirmação
>   antes de chamar um intent.
>
> Atenção: Se você invocar um intent e não houver um aplicativo
>   disponível no dispositivo para processar o intent, o aplicativo
>   falhará.
>
> Para confirmar se há atividade disponível para responder ao intent,
>   chame queryIntentActivities() para obter uma lista de atividades que
>   podem processar a Intent. Se o List retornado não estiver vazio, o
>   intent poderá ser usada com segurança.

Comment: Entendi, no entanto aqui na empresa me passaram que eu teria que fazer isso usando o conceito de OAuth 2.0. Você acha que eu consigo fazer isso usando o OAuth 2.0, ou não a necessidade ? Pois a ideia é termos N apps e dentro de um deles ter alguns "atalhos" para outros Apps, é não quero que o usuário quando troca de App não faça o login, já utilize a seção que ele esta logado.

Comment: Acredito que consiga sim  ja que o  Oauth é para  autenticação com sua conta. Recomendo olhar a documentação para o android, https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2 e https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/oauth2 . Acredito que ao criar a lista de aplicativos, voce possa passar as informações do mesmo. Na documentação eles colocam exemplos simples utilizando webservice junto ao OAUTH 2.0

Comment: particularmente falando nao utilizo muito o OAUTH pois estou produzindo programas fechados que nao requerem conexão entre si...
mas a base para chamar outro aplicativo é esta biblioteca que citei... quanto  ao Oauth ficarei devendo

Comment: tranquilo, suas informações já me dão um norte e tenho onde procurar algo, value :)

Comment: se foi util marca como resposta, para que mais pessoas possam ver também!

Comment: reformulei minha pergunta, grato pela atenção ;)